# ssh using jumpserver does not work in config

Tags: ssh

i try to connect to remote-server, going through jumpserver.
If i do:

ssh jumpserver (getting connected to jumpserver)

ssh username@remote-server (getting connected to remote-server through jumpserver)

it works just fine.

I have tried to create this config:

```
Host remote-server
  HostName 127.0.0.2
  User username
  ProxyCommand ssh jumpserver nc %h %p

Host remote-server
  HostName 127.0.0.2
  User username
  ProxyCommand ssh myuser@jumpserver nc %h %p
```

But when i try these configs in .ssh/config i am asked for password to root.

This command also works:
sh -o ProxyCommand='ssh jumpserver nc remote-server 22' username@remote-server

What am i missing in my config ?

Comment: they should be ok. You should use `-W` switch instead for jumpbox. Provide verbose log from both connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple settings hit the server, so it was my own fault... :(
Problem solved.